# Asynchronous calls to web-services - iPhone (PHP web-services)

Tags: iphone, web-services

Can anyone tell me about some classes which calls the web-services asynchronously. Currently I am writing all the asynchronous functions in the .m files of xibs but I want to write them in a separate files like web-service handler classes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In XCode, choose File/New, choose Cocoa Touch Class, choose Objective-C class.
Code up your web-services methods in this class.  You could use NSURL or [the  ASI library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest). 
You can instantiate this class from a view controller (for example).

Answer (score 0):

use ASIHTTPRequest to handle webservices .. read this blog -

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service